# Unexplained error to compile simple class function? C++

Tags: c++, compilation

As a beginner programer, I can't seem to catch what is going astray here. I removed some code to show that the error results from this simple syntax:

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Grader
{
public:
    Grader( );

    void addScore( int score )
    {
        vectorofints.push_back(score);
    }
    vector<int> vectorofints;
};

int main()
{
    Grader g;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The actual error message would be nice :(

Answer (score 6):

You've declared a constructor for `Grader` so must provide an implementation.  The easiest way to do this is to change

```
Grader( );
```

to

```
Grader( ) {}
```

Alternatively, if you just removed the declaration of the constructor, the compiler will generate it for you.